# Looping through girdview columns having more than one column type

Tags: c#, datagridview

First I will tell you some background, I needed to create a grid with dynamic columns, the column count would be based on user selection, in my DataTable, I added numbers to columns names to keep their name distinct, then I bind it with my girdview.

Now I need to rename columns headerText and remove the counter numbers from column headers, my gird has one more unbound column which is of type Image, when I try to loop my grid.columns using:

`foreach (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc in grdDistProcessing.Columns)`

it gives me error 
InvalidCastException:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'.**

I also used DataColumn but it gave me same error, another thread says we should use DataControlField but VS did not recognizing it, is it an ASP thing ? or I am missing a reference ?

Please Help.

Rgds,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the var keyword available to you (c#3 and above i think).

```
foreach (var dgc in grdDistProcessing.Columns)
{


 if(dgc is DataGridViewImageColumn)
{

   //do stuff with it.
   var tempDgc = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dgc; //cast it as needed.
   //use it

}


}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now when I type dgc, it does not give me intellisense, and I am not able to access dataGrid columns header text

Comment: @alphaprolix i've modified my answer to include casting it .. i'm sure you'll get the required intellisense now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks scartag, your solution is working like a charm, by the way I explored another solution for the issue, I can just use a plain for loop.

```
        `for (int i = 0; i < grdDistProcessing.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(grdDistProcessing.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }`
```